# amazon redshift sql: remove top 1% of data as outliers

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, postgresql-8.4

i'm trying to remove 1% of data as we consider those outliers that greatly skew data. i've tried using `SELECT TOP 99 PERC`, but Amazon Redshift does not support percentages with TOP.

I've tried something like:

```
WITH 
elapsed_times AS (
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(anonymous_id, distinct_id) as id,
    elapsed_time
  FROM studio_production.interaction
  WHERE project_id = '55062b464a9bc578006987ff'
),
max_elapsed_time AS (
  SELECT elapsed_time
  FROM elapsed_times
  ORDER BY elapsed_time ASC
  OFFSET ROUND(0.99 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elapsed_times))
  LIMIT 1
),
user_times AS (
  SELECT 
    id, 
    LEAST(elapsed_time, max_elapsed_time) as elapsed_time
  FROM elapsed_times
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT AVG(elapsed_time) FROM user_times
```

But I get: `argument of OFFSET must not contain subqueries`

thus, my query is now:

```
WITH 
elapsed_times AS (
  SELECT 
    COALESCE(anonymous_id, distinct_id) as id,
    elapsed_time,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY elapsed_time ASC) as rnk
  FROM studio_production.interaction
  WHERE project_id = '55062b464a9bc578006987ff'
), 
user_times AS (
  SELECT 
    id,
    LEAST(MAX(elapsed_time), (
      SELECT MIN(elapsed_time)
      FROM elapsed_times
      WHERE rnk > ROUND(0.99 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM elapsed_times))
    )) as elapsed_time
  FROM elapsed_times
  GROUP BY 1
)

SELECT AVG(elapsed_time) FROM user_times
```

which is actually quite slow. what is the correct approach to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

You could use `ntile()` (see [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_NTILE.html)):

```
select avg(elapsed_time)
from (select et.*,
             ntile(100) over (order by elapsed_time) as thetile
      from elapsed_times et
     ) et
where thetile not in (1, 100);
```

EDIT:

I admit that I often do this using `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
select avg(elapsed_time)
from (select et.*,
             row_number() over (order by elapsed_time) as seqnum,
             count(*) over () as cnt
      from elapsed_times et
     ) et
where (seqnum <= 0.01 * cnt) or (seqnum >= 0.99 * cnt);
```